# Swift: Performance comparision between class variables and variable inside the function

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am recently have used to design view controller programmatically. But declared unused labels, views in the class like below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var labelCreateYourAccount: UILabel = {
        
        let label = UILabel()
        
        self.addSubview(label)
        return label
    }()
}
```

But the label is not used anymore more than first time. For this case I will define a function setup() and will construct UI inside the function like below,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func setup(){
        
        let labelCreateYourAccount: UILabel  = .init()
        self.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

But I am not sure what are the performance impact between about two methods. Which is best way? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to use **millions** of such variables in order to create a difference in performance that **might** be detectable by a user.

This is a serious case of [**premature optimization**](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/). Use the approach that makes your code easier to write, understand, and maintain.